# react-chartjs-2 not rendering vertical arbitrary line using chartjs-plugin-annotation

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I am trying to show a arbitrary vertical line in my Line Chart. In line chart on X-Axis there is timestamp and on Y-Axis some data point integer.

I want to an arbitrary vertical line in my Line Chart on a specific timestamp. For that here is the options I have passed.

```
const options = {
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
        {
          drawTime: "afterDraw",
          id: "a-line-1",
          type: "line",
          mode: "horizontal",
          scaleID: "x",
          value: "12:15:45",
          borderColor: "red",
          borderWidth: 2
        }
      ]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        stepSize: 0,
        display: true,
        grid: {
          display: true, // Display y-axis grid lines
        },
      },
      x: { grid: { display: false } },
      Axes: [
        {
          grid: {
            display: false, // Hide vertical grid lines
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
  LineController,
  BarController,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation'

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, CategoryScale, BarElement, PointElement, LineElement, Legend, Tooltip, LineController, BarController );

const LineBarChart = ({ data, options, id }) => {
  return <Chart id={id} type='bar' data={data} options={options} plugins={ChartAnnotation} />;
};

export default LineBarChart;
```

But it is not rendering? What could be possible issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue: As mentioned at the top in `chartjs-plugin-annotation` [getting started](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/#getting-started):

> This plugin needs to be registered. It **does not function as inline plugin**.

You need to register the plugin instead of using inline-plugin:

```js
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
ChartJS.register(annotationPlugin);
```

Second issue: You are configuring plugins incorrectly. It shouldn't be in an array. Setup plugins under `options.plugins[plugin.id]`, where its id is `annotation`.

```js
const options = {
  plugins:{
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
         {
          drawTime: "afterDraw",
          id: "a-line-1",
          type: "line",
          // mode: "horizontal", // This will be ignored as it's not a valid property
          scaleID: "x",
          value: "12:15:45",
          borderColor: "red",
          borderWidth: 2,
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    y: {
      stepSize: 0,
      display: true,
      grid: {
        display: true, // Display y-axis grid lines
      },
    },
    x: { grid: { display: false } }
  },
};

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, CategoryScale, BarElement, PointElement, LineElement, Legend, Tooltip, LineController, BarController);
ChartJS.register(annotationPlugin);

const LineBarChart = ({ data, options, id }) => {
  return <Chart id={id} type='bar' data={data} options={options}/>;
};
```

---

Note: Besides the two main issues, there are more problems:

1. When you do `import * as ChartAnnotation from ...`, you are importing all available named exports. The Annotation plugin have to be accessed by `ChartAnnotation.default`. Hence, passing the whole `ChartAnnotation` is not correct. Instead you can `import ChartAnnotation from ...` as provided above.
2. While the chart still renders correctly, the `Axes` scale isn't being set correctly. If it's intended as a customized scale, [correct its format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/) based on the its [scale](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) [type](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html). Again, it shouldn't be in an array.

Comment: That worked. Thanks you. Actually I am facing one more issue that in labels array I got 8 points but when graph is rendered it shows only 3.

Comment: Yeah can't tell why from the existing code you've provided. You can either ask a new question or update a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/) link in this question.